# Enabled FBA & Windows Authentication on default zone

Tags: forms-authentication

I have enabled both authentication on default zone and on extranet zone, now when I want to open any document library on windows explorer it showing me a error

> "Your client does not support opening this list with Windows
>   Explorer."

and I am using SharePoint app in Android and IOS when I enabled FBA on a default zone authentication error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Haseeb,

Simply enable the [Desktop Experience](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772567.aspx) feature and you should be able to use "Open with Windows Explorer"

Please have a look at:
[Your client does not support opening this list with Windows Explorer](http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2010/07/08/your-client-does-not-support-opening-this-list-with-windows-explorer.aspx)

Comment: Its already enabled, web client service is also running on server. Windows exp. is working fine when FBA is not enabled on default zone.